# Basic Example and best practice of AngularJS Java EE web app

Tags: angularjs

If anyone has used AngularJS in a Java EE web app, then we will be grateful if you can provide any pointers/ examples of it.

What are the best practices, what is the ideal structure, design etc.
Any weblinks also will be helpful.

Comment: Excellent question, do not know why people down voted this.

Comment: @Polppan "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 12):

Since this is a very general question I'll answer it as such. There was a talk at jFall 2012 which demoed a very basic application with Java EE 6 and AngularJS which can be found here: https://github.com/teunh/jfall2012

I've been working on a school project which uses AngularJS as a frontend - JAX-RS as the restful interface and the basic backend logic in beans and database persistence with hibernate. I won’t be able to open source this project at the moment since it’s still a work in progress.

My experience and my message to you is that it's very easy to build a Java EE backend with an AngularJS frontend if you keep a restful interface in mind.

Comment: Vote up for Sharing Experience. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd only call this a valid question because there are simply so many ways to do web development these days (and yes, this same sentence would have been just as valid a year back). However, I would rather try answer a few underlying questions instead.

As per Oracle's official Java EE tutorials, which apply to both Java [6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html) and [7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/webapp.htm), by definition a "web application" is one of the follow two general types:

> Presentation-oriented: A presentation-oriented web application
>   generates interactive web pages containing various types of markup
>   language (HTML, XHTML, XML, and so on) and dynamic content in response
>   to requests.
>
> Service-oriented: A service-oriented web application implements the
>   endpoint of a web service. Presentation-oriented applications are
>   often clients of service-oriented web applications.

AngularJS is a front-end user interface framework. By the above definitions, this means Angular falls into the presentation-oriented category, without any server-side processing of it's own.

As for using this "in a Java EE app" as the question puts it.. Well, put quite simply, you don't. If you did try, you'd end up with either one `jsp` page spawning the entry point for your `ng-app`, or you'd end up with an `ng-app` that gets constantly reloaded as other `jsp` pages are loaded into the browser. Neither of these make use of technology to their full potential.

Your best bet is to set up a service-oriented Java EE application with a RESTful API, which your presentation-oriented AngularJS application would consume and present for the end user.

For what it's worth, [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFm45u1koOI) gives a nice clear overview of something like this in action.